# MetaMask - Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: solidity, metamask, javascript, nodejs, bsc

i was developing a full stack nft marketplace, where i can mint nfts but when i try to buy it gives me this error :MetaMask - Internal JSON-RPC error

```
code: 3, message: "execution reverted: Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase", data:
```

along with this:Uncaught (in promise)

any solution

Comment: You should probably share the contract part reverting in this case. That you developed?!

Comment: any clear idea.?

Comment: Can you show the contract code? How the transaction is sent to the contract?